# Simulator keeps crashing in Xcode 4.4

Tags: iphone, ios, simulator, xcode4.4

When ever I run my app in Xcode 4.4 the simulator fails to open, "iOS Simulator quit unexpectedly." It runs on perfectly on the device though.

Comment: Hi, you have resolve the problem? I have the same problem, and now i download with Xcode 4.5 and sdk 6, I'll tell you if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by installing xcode 4.5 and ios sdk 6. Now all work fine.

Comment: This worked for me as well, also with the recent OSX Mountain Lion update it works in Xcode 4.4 as well

Answer (score 1):

You may have had a bad build on the Simulator, which is now messing things up.

- Clean your code `(Product > Clean in XCode)`
- Reset your simulator settings `(iOS Simulator menu > Reset Content and Settings)`

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem i just did following steps and it works fine

1) Reset your iPhone simulator

2) Clean Build your code

3) Restart your computer

Its works for me.

Comment: how do you reset the iphone simulator

Comment: Click on "iOS Simulator" from Menu.  Then click on "Rest content and Setting". Then Click on "Reset"

Comment: unfortunately the simulator never opens so I'm unable to reset

Comment: I can't find the simulator application anywhere

Comment: With Xcode 4.4 the path to the simulator application is /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app. With other Xcode versions the path may be different.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot the simulator ..... sometimes some apps remain in the memory.... Otherwise reinstall it ... some data could be corrupt... :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Lion.
After upgrade to Mountain Lion I haven't such issue.

Comment: I am running Mountain Lion :(